# What is the best and most efficient way to get data by JavaScript from EntityFramework database in my case?

Tags: javascript, c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Right now in my ASP.NET MVC Core2 project I have a model in `EF database`, that contains several properties:

```
public class SchoolEvents
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(40, ErrorMessage = "Max 40 characters")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime WhenHappens { get; set; }
    }
```

I have no problem to get data from the `EF database` by MVC `Razor Views`. But I am using `JavaScript` Calendar plugin in one of my Views, that will mark events from `db` on it. To do it, the script is taking data in format:

```
{ title: 'EventTitle', description: 'Few words about the event', datetime: new Date(2018, 8, 14, 16) }
```

It seems to be obvious, that I supposed to use a `for` loop in the script, iterating on `db` objects.

As I am still noob about `JS`, right now the only way I know to do it is:

-to create JSON file in the controller:

```
[Route("events")]
        [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public ActionResult Comments()
        {
            var _events= _context.Events.OrderBy(c => c.ProductID).ToList(); //yes, I know, I should use repository in the best practice
            return Json(_events);
        }
```

-in `JS` file I can use kinf of `loadEventsFromServer()` function, that uses `XMLHttpRequest` or `Fetch` and parsing it (I do not know yet how to do the parsing, I will be happy to get some suggestions),

And that it is it. Do you have some other ideas how to do it?

**EDIT**:

Update with part of plugins code, for console error `d is undefined`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
                var cDay = $('<div/>');
                if (i < dWeekDayOfMonthStart) {
                    cDay.addClass('c-day-previous-month c-pad-top');
                    cDay.html(dLastDayOfPreviousMonth++);
                } else if (day <= dLastDayOfMonth) {
                    cDay.addClass('c-day c-pad-top');
                    if (day == dDay && adMonth == dMonth && adYear == dYear) {
                        cDay.addClass('c-today');
                    }
                    for (var j = 0; j < settings.events.length; j++) {
                        var d = settings.events[j].datetime;
                        if (d.getDate() == day && d.getMonth() == dMonth && d.getFullYear() == dYear) {
                            cDay.addClass('c-event').attr('data-event-day', d.getDate());
                            cDay.on('mouseover', mouseOverEvent).on('mouseleave', mouseLeaveEvent);
                        }
                    }
                    cDay.html(day++);
                } else {
                    cDay.addClass('c-day-next-month c-pad-top');
                    cDay.html(dayOfNextMonth++);
                }
                cBody.append(cDay);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use ajax request.

> Javascript : Ajax

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@URL.Action("Comments","Controller")',
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
             var events = new Object();
                events = $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < data.d.length; j++) {
                        var event = new Object();                            
                        var startDate = Date.parse(item.WhenHappens )
                        event.start = startDate;                           
                        event.title = item.Title;
                        event.backgroundColor = "#c6458c";
                        event.description = item.Description;
                        return event;
                    }
                })
                callCalender(events);
            },
            error:function(e){  

            }
        });
```

> Controller

```
[Route("events")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult Comments()
    {
        var _events= _context.Events.OrderBy(c => c.ProductID).ToList(); //yes, I know, I should use repository in the best practice
        return Json(_events);
    }
```

Comment: Cool approach, but I am getting console error `d is undefined`, and I am guessing it is `d` from the calendar's plugin. I updated the question with part of plugins code.

Comment: P.S. after writing `console.log(event);` or `console.log(start);` before returning event in your code I am not getting anyting at all in my console.

Comment: Temporay I managed to make it work with using MVC Component and using in it mix of `JS` and `Razor` code: `events: [
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <text>
                    { title: '@item.Title', description: '@item.Description', datetime: new Date('@item.WhenHappens.Year', @item.WhenHappens.Month-1, '@item.WhenHappens.Day', '@item.WhenHappens.Hour')},
                    </text>
                }
                ]` I wonder how to make it work using plain `JS`

Comment: Try to set debugger in the success of ajax and find what you are getting in data of success function.

Comment: Just place `debugger` before `var events` and find what you get in data that will make sense what data you get and you need to work on that..

Comment: Kindly Check may Sample and this link https://github.com/niks2060/FullCalenderSample/blob/master/index.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort! I will study your example when I have more time today. Now I understand `callCalender` function and how it supposed to be used. `JS` is still black magic for me, but I want to change it when I finish this project. I like `ajax` calls, also I want to learn to use `fetch` in the future, they seems to be more simple. By using `ajax` with `jquery` is it efficient to call whole `jquery`? Right now I will stay with my `asp.net component` way to call and iterate db objects. But I will study your example soon for sure.

Comment: I dind't get you in `ajax with jquery is it efficient to call whole jquery?` what does exactly you want to say..?